# 1 email notification for each user

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

I have a custom list in SharePoint 2010.This list is to collect the metrics from each POC,which means each POC will have multiple metrics/items to update.

Is there any way that I can send 1 email notification(using SharePoint Designer workflow) for each POC for all the metrics he has to update?

Comment: It is hard to create such a workflow because workflows are tied to a single item. Also loop etc will be difficult in case of 2010

Comment: @AmalHashim Thanks for your reply. Or is there any way that I can consolidate/collate all the items ID in a column, assigned to each POC? using calculated column/javascript/xslt

Comment: If it is on-premise can't you use Timer Job?